# Testing the Outlook REST API leads to suspended account issue

Tags: node.js, outlook-restapi, outlook-web-app

I'm trying to integrate Outlook Mail with a web app I'm working on. I need to do some tests with the API during the development. I'm using the node-outlook library in my NodeJS app. However, after sending a few test emails to both real and dummy addresses, I encountered the following error:

> *"REST request returned 530; body: {"error":{"code":"ErrorAccountSuspend","message":"Account suspended.
>   Follow the instructions in your Inbox to verify your account., WASCL
>   UserAction verdict is not None. Actual verdict is Suspend,
>   ShowTierUpgrade."}}"*

It seems that Microsoft detected unusual activity with my account and suspends the account. I followed the directions and verified my account in a process that included mobile phone verification. It seemed the problem was resolved.

Now, I see that I can read the messages through the API, however I cannot use the API to send new emails or send draft emails. Also it seems I cannot send emails in the Outlook web app, too. I receive the same "suspended account" error.

One question is how can I solve this problem? Do any restrictions of "suspended account" error remain in place even after verifying the account and resolving the problem?

Another general question is, how can I do different tests with the Outlook API during development, without causing this "suspended account" error? I did much more tests with the Gmail API without any such problems.

Comment: Have you found any documentation about this issue from MS? Or any solutions yet? Thanks for the post.

Comment: I actually followed the process suggested by Microsoft to resolve the suspension of my account. Since then, I've not had any other problem and I've been able to send test emails without any more suspend issues. 
I'm not sure whether this was the result of resolving the initial suspension, or Microsoft has improved its tolerance for detecting fake and spam emails.